# Mapping different classes to the same database table

Tags: python, object-oriented, design-patterns, database, django

I have several very similar subclasses that I (think I) want to be stored in the same database table. Most of the fields are identical, with each subclass adding 1 or 2 custom fields. My code is using the Django ORM, but I think the question is more general than that.

### Problem specification

The app is meant to simplify the tracking and submission of corporate expenses for reimbursement. There are three primary user interactions:

1. **Inputting expenses**: The user says "I just took a $25 cab to the airport for a client visit, billable to XXX client."
2. **Viewing expenses**: The users says "Did I forget to add that dinner from last Tuesday? Let me see if this is the one I'm thinking of..."
3. **Generating reports**: The user says "Compile these 15 expenses into the XML report I need to submit these to finance for reimbursement."

The report itself is pretty standard xml, with one node per expense, with each field given its own node (roughly, `<trxs><trx><date>YYYY-MM-DD</date>...</trx><trx>...</trx><trxs>`). **The key complication** is that depending on the type of expense, there are **1 or 2 additional custom fields** per transaction. E.g., airfare expenses require a `ticket_number`, taxi expenses require `destination` and `purpose` fields, etc. These fields show up in the XML report roughly as

```
<custom>%%%destination%%%Airport%%%purpose%%%client travel%%%</custom>
```

The XML schema for all expense types is thus the same.

### Current solution

There is a single `Transaction` model, which mirrors the XML schema and has fields like `item_date`, `amount`, `client_code`, `employee_id`, etc.  It also has a `custom` field, which stores the custom fields, serialized the same way they are serialized in the XML report.

In order to keep the custom field seralization/deserialization code near the model, I've [used Django proxy models](http://benlopatin.com/using-django-proxy-models/) to create subclasses that map to the same table but provide slightly different functionality.

```
from django.db import models

class Transaction(models.Model):

    MEAL = '5'
    # ...
    TAXI = '2'

    EXPENSE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (MEAL, 'Meal'),
        # ...
        (TAXI, 'Taxi'),
    )

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    item_date = models.DateField()
    expense_type = models.CharField(choices=EXPENSE_TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=4)
    # ...
    custom = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def as_subclass(self):
        if self.expense_type == self.MEAL:
            self.__class__ = MealTrx
        elif self.expense_type == self.TAXI:
            self.__class__ = TaxiTrx
        # ...
        else:
            raise ValueError("Expense type not set!")


class MealTrx(Transaction):
    objects = TypedManager({'expense_type': Transaction.MEAL})
    # TypedManager adds .filter(**kwargs) to .get_queryset()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    detail_re = re.compile("^%%%attendees%%%(.*)%%%purpose%%%(.*)$")
    detail_str = "%%%attendees%%%{}%%%purpose%%%{}"

    @property
    def attendees(self): # Comma-separated list of attendees
        match =  self.detail_re.match(self.custom)
        if match is None:
            return []
        return match.group(1).split(", ")

    @attendees.setter
    def attendees(self, value):
        args = (", ".join(value), self.purpose)
        self.custom = self.detail_str.format(*args)

    @property
    def purpose(self):
        match =  self.detail_re.match(self.custom)
        if match is None:
            return ""
        return match.group(2)

    @purpose.setter
    def purpose(self, value):
        args = (", ".join(self.attendees), value)
        self.custom = self.detail_str.format(*args)
```

### How the code gets called

#### 1. Creating expenses

This takes place inside the new transaction form `save()` method. The attributes are assigned and the model is saved. The property setters ensure that the fields are properly serialized:

```
def save(self):
    trx = base_form.save(commit=False)  # base_form is a ModelForm for Transaction
    trx.as_subclass()
    if trx.expense_type == models.Transaction.MEAL:
        trx.attendees = self.meal_form.cleaned_data['attendees']
        trx.purpose = self.meal_form.cleaned_data.get('purpose', "")
    elif trx.expense_type == models.Transaction.TAXI:
    # ...
    trx.save()
    return trx
```

#### 2. Viewing expenses

This takes place inside template code, where the approach is to test for all of the possible custom fields:

```
def expense_detail(request, expense_id):
    expense = get_object_or_404(models.Transaction, pk=expense_id)
    expense.as_subclass()
    if expense.user != request.user:
        LOGGER.warning("%r tried to see details of Transaction %s",
                       request.user.username, expense_id)
        raise http.Http404
    return render(request, 'expenses/detail.html', {'expense': expense})
```

and then inside the `Jinja2` template

```
{%- if expense.attendees -%}
  <div class="table-row">
    <span class="table-cell">Attendees</span>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <ul class="attendee-list">
        {%- for attendee in expense.attendees -%}
          <li>{{ attendee }}</li>
        {%- endfor -%}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
{%- endif -%}
```

#### 3. Generating reports

This is the most straightforward piece, since the database schema mirrors the XML schema. Roughly speaking:

```
class Report:
    # snip
    def to_string(self, encoding='utf-8'):
        # build the document root, header info, etc.
        for trx in self. transactions:
            transactions.append(self.trx_as_element(trx))
        return ET.tostring(root, encoding=encoding)

    def trx_as_element(self, trx):
        root = ET.Element('doc_trans')
        items = [
            ('item_date', transaction.item_date.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")),
            ('expense_type', transaction.expense_type),
            # ...
            ('custom', transaction.custom),
        ]
        for key, val in items:
            ET.SubElement(root, key).text = val
        return root
```

### Identified issues

1. Adding a new expense type requires modifying a lot of places
2. There's a lot of repetition in the definition of properties
3. I'm not super-comfortable with the assignment of `__class__` in `as_subclass()`. That feels too magic, and asking client code to remember to call `as_subclass()` seems like a bad idea
4. Accessing and modifying the custom properties is expensive (I think), requiring 1 or 2 regex matches and string interpolation every time

---

**Bottom-line**: Is this code readable? Understandable? Easy to use? Would adding a new expense type, or creating a view to edit existing expenses be unduly painful?

Comment: Is this actual, working code, or hypothetical and stub code? I'm a little uncertain whether this is good for Code Review or not...

Comment: This is coming from deployed code. I tried slimming it down to focus on the key points. Happy to add more code if helpful

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is a `CustomField` parent class (with `TaxiField` and `MealField` as subclasses).

Then you use implement some getters and setter on your `Transaction` Model to retrieve those models.

In your `CustomField` you can then implement a `__str__` method to simply call `('custom', str(transaction.custom))` when you need to render it.

In the `CustomField` parent class, you can store the subfields as an `OrderedDict` and create getters and setters like: `set(field_name, field_value)` (to prevent method like `attendees()`)

Comment: Thanks -- I think this is a good idea to encapsulate a lot of this repetitive behavior and potentially get rid of the `__class__` assignment. It might even help with the template code. I'll work on it a bit and post back

Comment: Sure, please comment on this answer when you have your new code, so that I can have the chance to look at it :-)